# Regular Expression Validator Error in Dialog Box in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, validation

Is it possible to show the error message of a Regular Expression validator in Asp.net into a message box/ dialog box?

I've tried everything i knew but nothing works for me.

Thanks alot

Comment: Alert Message Box is ok for you ??

Comment: How to apply this Alert Message in my Regular Expression Validator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Label ID="lblNameRequired" runat="server" Text="*Name :"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNameRequired" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Validation"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorName" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtNameRequired"
        Display="None" ErrorMessage="Name is Required" ValidationGroup="Validation"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblGenderRequired" runat="server" Text="*Gender :"></asp:Label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGenderRequired" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Validation">
        <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="-1">--Select--</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="0">Male</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="1">Female</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidatorGender" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlGenderRequired"
        Display="None" ErrorMessage="Gender is Required" Operator="NotEqual" ValidationGroup="Validation"
        ValueToCompare="-1"></asp:CompareValidator>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblValidation" runat="server" Text="Fields marked with * are required"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnValidate" runat="server" Text="Validate Input" ValidationGroup="Validation" />
    <br />
    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" ShowMessageBox="True"
        ShowSummary="False" ValidationGroup="Validation" />
    </form>
```

use the same ValidationGroup text on all validation controls and add a ValidationSummary with the ValidationGroup and ShowMessageBox="true"